# PHP: weird behaviour when calling a protected method via a static proxy

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3

I find this really strange..could someone give an explanation?

```
abstract class UIController{
   public static function exec($context,$vdo){
      return call_user_func(array($context, $vdo));   
   }
}

class UIControllerSettings extends UIController{
    protected function save(){
        return "saved\n";
    }
}

$controller = new UIControllerSettings();
echo UIController::exec($controller, 'save'); //<-- prints "saved"
echo $controller->save(); // <-- throws a fatal error
```

Not sure it this makes sense;
shouldn't both calls produce a fatal error??

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Here is the output:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  3 2011 00:48:48) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
$ php test.php 
saved
PHP Fatal error:  Call to protected method UIControllerSettings::save() from context '' in test.php on line 17
```

Comment: The first one doesnt cause an error, but it isnt "okay". As far as I can see it should output "saved", but I tried it myself and it returned nothing.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @Demian: `Fatal`, its mentioned at the source. However, the line above the failing one should fail too (also mentioned in the question).

Comment: @king: Woops, somehow I missed that. Apparently I need coffee ;)

Comment: `Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php. Since `UIController::exec()` is the right way to address the public static function, my guess is the call_use_func() is being processed as a call from within the class itself. On the other hand `$controler->save()` can't be run because it's a protected function.

Comment: thanks for your fast responses; plz check the update.

Comment: PENDO, please make your comment an answer.

Comment: hehe, still getting used to stackoverflow. I wasn't completely sure I had it by the right end as I was guessing the call_user_func() part.. but it seems right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes:`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php.

Since `UIController::exec()` is the right way to address the public static function, my guess is the call_use_func() is being processed as a call from within the class itself. On the other hand `$controler->save()` can't be run because it's a protected function.

Comment: I see your point; that's probably it. But isn't this a bug? I'm not just calling the protected method from inside the `UIController` class. The `UIController::exec()` method calls a protected method of the object $context, which just happens to be a instance of the child class `UIControllerSettings`. Looks more like a bug to me :-/

Comment: It's normal behaviour. Your `exec()` function is doing the work by calling `call_user_func()` which in it's turn is calling the `save()` function. Because `exec()` is a method of UIController everything within this method has enough privileges to run private functions/alter private variables and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Protected methods can be called anywhere in the inheritance line of the object(parents and children). Because `UIController::exec` which is in `UIController` that is a parent of `UIControllerSettings` is actually calling `UIControllerSettings::save` and not the main code it is perfectly ok.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure it's entirely correct (could be).

I'm not just calling the protected method from inside the UIController class. The UIController::exec() method calls a protected method of the object $context, which just happens to be a instance of the child class UIControllerSettings

Comment: If you try to call a protected method of any other class it will fail. it works just because its in the same inheritance line.